# How do we enable OpenMP to use multiple cores -- glintenet

Tags: r, parallel-processing, classification, openmp, cpu-cores

I want to use glinternet a R function that implements a feature extraction methodology developed by the Stanford professor Trevor Hastie and a PhD student.

The function has an argument numCores.  According to the user manual:

> numCores Number of threads to run. For this to work, the package must
>   be installed with OpenMP enabled. Default is 1 thread.

I don't know though how to enable OpenMP. I have Windows 8.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: You must install the compiler corresponding to your choice of R implementation and check its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of the glinternet package maintainer about this issue : "Unfortunately, R does not support openmp on windows. If you have access to a linux machine, you will likely be able to use the parallelism there."