# Compile a R package with OpenMP support

Tags: r, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to use the R package glinternet, which has an option "nCores", standing for the number of threads to run.

According to the user manual, for this to work, the package must be installed with OpenMP enabled. This sentence is very vague to me.

I have checked the "MakeConf" file, in which I have found the following lines :

```
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FCFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS = -fopenmp
```

Adding these lines on a file called "MakeVars" did not help either :

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS=-fopenmp
PKG_LIBS= -fopenmp -lgomp
```

I am using R 3.4.1 on Windows 10, and installed the package using the standard install.packages() procedure.

PS : The answer given in this post was not understandable for me : [How do we enable OpenMP to use multiple cores -- glintenet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363939/how-do-we-enable-openmp-to-use-multiple-cores-glintenet)

**EDIT**

I have tried installing the package from the Windows terminal. I would say everything is ok since I can see many lines refering to gcc and/or openmp. For instance I can see :

```
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include" -fopenmp -O2 -Wall -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c c_routines.c -o c_routines.o
```

However it did not improve the execution time of the package functions.

Comment: These options require some form of gcc as the compiler.  If the documentation doesn't describe a Windows build, and you are totally unfamiliar with gcc, and unwilling to check documentation, it may be a difficult row to  hoe.  If you choose a Microsoft compiler, there is an old subset of OpenMP with different spellings of those options.

Comment: Here is the answer of the glinternet package maintainer about this issue : "Unfortunately, R does not support openmp on windows. If you have access to a linux machine, you will likely be able to use the parallelism there."